# What is the largest value of k to make 3 to the power of k a product of 30 factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Given the expression $30! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4\cdot\ldots \cdot 30$:
>
> What is the largest value of $k$ such that $3^k\mid30!$ ? Show your work.

This was a question in the math exam I wrote recently and I managed to work out a solution by isolating the multiples of $3$ as well as considering obvious $3^x$ values such as $3$,$9$ and $27$, however: upon discussion with my friends as well as speaking to a math teacher, I discovered many different approaches to the solution with, alas, quite a few different k values which all seemed "correct": such as $16$,  or $24$, or $49$. That is why my aim is not just to determine the correct answer, but to determine the correct approach to the question and thus the solution.

Any assistance would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every multiple of $3$ contributes at least one $3$. Every multiple of $9$ contributes another $3$. Every multiple of $27$ contributes another $3$ etc. So you count the multiples of $3$: there are $10$. Then you count the multiples of $9$: there are just 3 $9,18,27$. Then you count the multiples of $27$: there's only the one. So the answer is $10+3+1=14$. This method of proof leads to a famous formula for the exponent of $p$ in $k!$:
$[k/p]+[k/p^2]+[k/p^3]+\cdots$ where the brackets refer to the greatest integer or "rounding down" function. In our case we have $[30/3]+[30/9]+[30/27]=10+3+1.$

Answer (score 0):

Isolating the multiples of 3 is the way to go. In 30!,

3*6*9*12*15*18*21*24*27*30

includes

1+1+2+1+1+2+1+1+3+1 '3's in its index notation, which is equal to 14.

Thus, the answer is 14.